# Apache, mysql ivestigation needed!

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

I have problem with server, all works fine but then suddenly server load increases to 12-25 and when i restart apache and mysql the load is dropping, and after few days 1-2 load again increases :(

Can you advice me methods which i can use to investigate and fix this annoying problem?

Comment: Please write more information about your system. Which services running? Which operating system?

Comment: You gave as _lot of information_ I am pretty sure you will get your answer as soon as possible... are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

install mod_status on Apache and mtop for Mysql to be able to see which requests are made.

Are you sure that you don't have set up some big values in my.cnf which are taking all the RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Set up monitoring software and monitor at least CPU, IO and MEM.